# JavaScript not run in Webview in android 3.0

Tags: javascript, android, webview

In Android 3.0 + webview support the svg file for display.
i have set all svg images and java script in assets folder.

Using this code am able to see svg in webview.

```
myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/00011_1.svg");
```

but for `java script` i have used this code

```
myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/00011_1.svg?text=aaaaa&sig=bbbbb");
```

but WebView  show that webPage not availble .

How can i figure out?

Please help me out.

Thanks
Parag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `file://` scheme does not support query parameters, AFAIK.

As a workaround, after the SVG has been loaded, use:

```
myBrowser.loadUrl("javascript:...");
```

where the `...` is replaced by JavaScript source code that passes in your desired values to some global function.